# Cannot Withdraw BTCpay Balance...Assistance Needed

Tags: electrum, btcpay

I have tried to be as detailed as possible.

I setup a BTCpay store.  When setting up the wallet I used a xPub key, that I own the private keys to.  These private keys are attached to my blockchain.com wallet.  Previously, when I received payments through BTCpay the payments would appear in my blockchain.com wallet, because that is where the xPub key originated.

The problem:  The BTCpay payments are not appearing in my blockchain.com wallet, but only on the BTCpay wallet page.

The solution: I either need to be able to send my bitcoin out from BTCpay or access it via my private keys through a wallet, like Electrum.

When I try to send out the bitcoin from the BTCpay wallet it states that I am using the wrong derivation path, but I have tried the following-
•   m/84'/0'/0'
•   m/44'/0'/0'
•   m/44'/0'

I was told that the reason the payments don’t show in my blockchain.com wallet is because of a Gap Limit problem, basically my blockchain.com wallet stopped fetching the payments from BTCpay.  Blockchain.com wallets don’t allow changing the Gap Limit. Two wallets were suggested that allow the Gap Limit to be raised, Wasabi and Electrum.  When I entered my private keys into Wasabi, my balance showed zero and no transaction history.  When I entered my private keys into Electrum (native segwit) my balance is zero, but a transaction history shows up until May 2023.  In my blockchain.com wallet I do currently have a balance and many transactions since May 2023.  In my Electrum wallet I increased the Gap Limit to 500, but still shows zero balance.

Can anyone assist me with sending out my balance from BTCpay?

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate that I'm not an expert in all the fields you cover but I see the question has been unanswered approaching a week, so here's how I'd approach it.

Your's seems to be a single problem: the private keys that started at blockchain.com no longer show activity there because of the site's gap limit, and while they do show activity with BTCpay, seem not to be usable for sending out.

I'd suggest getting those keys into a new Bitcoin Core instance, then moving those funds from *there* to a wallet you trust. This approach forces your device to rescan the blockchain and so avoids the gap limit issue.

VERY carefully review [Husna QA's instructions here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5410469.msg60862607#msg60862607): while Core has never directly accepted seed phrases, it does seem a reasonable path from a creditable source to converting them. Also carefully review the follow-up discussion.

Comment: Thank you.  I am still dealing with this gap limit issue.  I will investigate your suggestion further.